# React using TypeScript, Don't use {} as a type. {

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, lint

I am getting an ESlint error `` Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value". `` in my Contact component whiling using React and TypeScript.

The component doesn't have any props.

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component<{}, MyState> {
    constructor(props = {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            signedUp: false,
        };
    }
}
```

I tried using `null` instead, but that threw other ESLint errors.

Comment: Would `unknown` do? Or may be even `never`

Comment: I did not try never, but unknown created issues of it's own.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found the following GitHub issues.

By adding the following to your `.eslintrc.js` you are able to ignore the rule. It is recommended to use [Configurations](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns) to have this rule only apply to React components. This will ensure strong typing everywhere else.

```
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "extendDefaults": true,
        "types": {
          "{}": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492

Comment: Excerpt from the link above: `If you are using React, and you want to define type Props = {}.
This is technically safe in this instance, because under the hood the {} type is passed into an intersection type (see the note at the end of this comment for why this is safe).` explains why this is safe to do in react. I'm not sure you want to turn this off everywhere. @Iboyel answer seems more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on Jordan answer to apply this rule to only React components in the `.eslintrc.js` file add

```
overrides: [
    {
        // Apply rule override only to files with the following extensions
        files: ['*.tsx', '*.jsx'],
        rules: {
            '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
                'error',
                {
                    extendDefaults: true,
                    types: {
                        '{}': false,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `{[k: string | number | symbol]: never}` work in place of `{}` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be complete code, right?

Comment: "files" should be an array of two values `['*.tsx', '*.jsx']`

Comment: I'd argue that Middlewares would normally live in `ts` files. So `['*.ts', '*.tsx']` seems more correct to me.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly disagree that the chosen answer is correct. This warning exists for a reason; for anyone Googling it, I'll leave it as what ESLint says:

> - If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
> - If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
> - If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead.