# How to define a completely unknown incoming JSON field in a type?

Tags: typescript

I have models coming from a backend with a metadata field that can be any valid JSON with no guaranteed schema:

```json
{
  "unknown_field" : "Apple",
  "unknown_field_2" : 13
}
```

I'm trying to write a type to intake this:

```js
type MyModel{
   id : string
   name : string
   metadata : {} // <- obviously not working
}
```

What's the proper way to define metadata here? The examples I search for keep proposing defining a known schema with optional fields, which is not what I have.

Edit:

`metadata : {}` does not work and gives this message:

"don't use '{}' as a type. '{}' actually means any non-nullish value"

Comment: Can you be more specific than just saying that your type definition isn't working? `metadata: {}` should allow any object as a value, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Updated with the message I got from using `metadata : {}`. I agree, intuitively that should be what I want.

Comment: Thanks! Posted an answer that accounts for that error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ESLint? By default your type definition seems valid, other than missing a few symbols:

```js
type MyModel = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  metadata: {};
}
```

You can configure ESLint to ignore this rule (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773897/react-using-typescript-dont-use-as-a-type)).

Alternatively, try either of these types instead:

```js
type MyModel1 = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  metadata: object;
}

type MyModel2 = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  metadata: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

Comment: I see thanks, I am using ESLint. New to the stack so I don't know the difference between ESLint and Typescript problems.

Comment: You're welcome! And that's no problem, I'm happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If it can really be anything your only option is using `any` type.

If you're getting some dictionary, you could try to narrow it down to something like this .:

```
metadata: { [key:string]: any }
```

Which would at least indicate that you're dealing with something that has keys at the first level

Comment: Thanks! Can I use `metadata: { [key:string]: unknown }`?

Comment: I believe so, but to be honest i never really used this in practice - at work I'm stuck with older typescript version which don't have this feature yet